# Pandas: Assign column from single-indexed df to multi-indexed df

Tags: python, pandas

Consider three dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1,2,3], 'a': [1,1,2], 'b': [10,20,10], 'c':[100, 200, 300]}).set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2': [1,3,4], 'a': [1,2,2], 'b': [10,10,20]}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x3': [1,4], 'a': [1,2]}).set_index('a')
```

If I do

```
df1['x2'] = df2['x2']
```

pandas will match the multiindex properly and `df1` will contain:

```
                x1  x2
a   b   c       
1   10  100     1   1.0
    20  200     2   NaN
2   10  300     3   3.0
```

However, if I do:

```
df1['x3'] = df3['x3']
```

Result would be:

```
                x1  x3
a   b   c       
1   10  100     1   NaN
    20  200     2   NaN
2   10  300     3   NaN
```

I am, of course, expecting to get `x3 = [1, 1, 4]` instead of all `NaNs`. I guess this is because df3 doesn't have a Multiindex? Is there some nice way to do this, without merging on index or reindexing?

Comment: Maybe `df1.combine_first(df3)`?

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work! Do you know what the efficiency of it is?

I found that manually turning single-index of df3 into multiindex by:
```df3.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(idx,) for idx in df3.index], names=[df3.index.name])```
works as well, but I wouldn't really call that elegant.